# Swagger Pass parameter to handler

Tags: go, swagger

I am using go-swagger, with a definition:

```
  /somethings:
    get:
      produces:
      - text/plain
      tags:
      - somethings
      summary: some summary
      operationId: GetSomethings
      responses:
        "200":
          description: some summary
          schema:
            type: string
```

I have a handler for this:

```
 package impl

 func GetSomethingsHandlerFunc(params metrics.GetSomethingsParams, namespace string) middleware.Responder {
     return middleware.ResponderFunc....
 }
```

`GetSomethingsParams` is autogenerated as:

```
type GetMetricsParams struct {

    // HTTP Request Object
    HTTPRequest *http.Request `json:"-"`
}
```

In configureAPI function:

```
api.SomethingsGetHandler = somethings.GetSomethingsHandlerFunc(impl.GetSomethingsHandlerFunc, "some_namespace_value")
```

How do I pass this `namespace` string (that is : `"some_namespace_value"`) to the impl.GetSomethingsHandlerFunc?